# Puppeteer Screen Recording at scale

Tags: node.js, .net, selenium-webdriver, automation, puppeteer

I have a very specific use case for Puppeteer.

Visit a website & record a screen recording of scrolling through their website

At scale, this renders videos for 1,000s of websites & saves them.

Problem: this takes very long, and if a user creates 10,000 videos, my current tech stack  take a long time. (Playwright, .Net, AWS Lambda) - takes about 3 mins to make a single 30 second recording.

As we grow in user-base, we'll need to do 100,000+ daily. As a non-tech founder, how can I do this at such heavy scale? Please if you can mention outsourcing power to Dockers/Cloudflare etc to speed it up, that would be good too.

My current tech stack (Playwright, .Net, AWS Lambda) - takes about 3 mins to make a single 30 second recording, when competitors make videos in less than 5 seconds.